# Disable Apply Action Button When Start or End Date is null - MatDateRangePicker

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using `mat-date-range-picker-actions` buttons in `mat-date-range-picker`. I want to disable
apply (`matDateRangePickerApply`) action button if `start` of range or `end` of range is `null`.

I have tried to use `formGroup.invalid` on the apply button with `disabled` without any success. Also,
I have tried to use `dateChange()` function on `start` and `end` inputs of the date range, but they do not called without clicking on apply button. The problem is that, every time these functions are called after pressing the apply button. Therefore, I cannot disable the apply button dynamically.

**What I Want?**

I just want to disable the apply button of [this](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#datepicker-actions) date range if `start` or `end` of date range is null.

**HTML Code:**

```
<mat-form-field class="form-control" appearance="fill">
  <mat-date-range-input [formGroup]="range" [rangePicker]="dateRangePicker">
    <input
      (dateChange)="dateChanged('start', $event)"
      formControlName="start"
      matStartDate
      placeholder="Start date"
    />
    <input
      (dateChange)="dateChanged('end', $event)"
      formControlName="end"
      matEndDate
      placeholder="End date"
    />
  </mat-date-range-input>

  <mat-datepicker-toggle
    matSuffix
    [for]="dateRangePicker"
  ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-date-range-picker #dateRangePicker>
    <mat-date-range-picker-actions>
      <button mat-button matDateRangePickerCancel>Cancel</button>
      <button
        mat-raised-button
        matDateRangePickerApply
        (click)="applyDateRange()"
      >
        Apply
      </button>
    </mat-date-range-picker-actions>
  </mat-date-range-picker>
</mat-form-field>
```

**My Component:**

```
export class AppComponent {
  range = new FormGroup({
    start: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
    end: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
  });
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.range.valueChanges.subscribe(_val => {
      console.log(_val, this.range.invalid); // <<<<----------------- not comes here until click on apply button
    });
  }

  applyDateRange(): void {}

  dateChanged(_type: "start" | "end", _event): void {
    console.log(_type, _event); // <<<<----------------- not comes here until click on apply button
  }
}
```

So, if we select a date on the calendar, we should receive a value selected. Then I can disable or enable the apply button if both start and end have a value.

Here is the stackblitz.com [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gemcka?file=src/app/app.component.html) of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know its been a year and a half since you posted, but here is patchy solution.
mat-date-range-input has a required input, which will set the date picker in invalid state if the user clicked on apply without choosing end date, and it has nice ui to show its invalid (similar to FormField).
You could then check whenever the date picker state is valid and only then perform some logic.

Its not perfect solution and I did not find a way to disable the apply button since, as you stated, both the form, and the matEndDate, fire events only AFTER the user press apply.

I tried using viewChild to get the matEndDate and listen to its state, which was invalid, but only after the user pressed apply, and there was no indication the date picker was invalud.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Although your insight may be valuable and solve the OP issue, it will be more instructive for him and others if you post some nice formatted code showing how to do it correctly; as stated, your answer is much like a comment. And posting code increases the odds for you get upvoted.